# how to load data from server using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to load data from server using AJAX but the data is not loading and I don't know why. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js">. 
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        $("#test").load("data.txt");
    });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">
<p>This is the first content!</p>
</div>


<button id="btn">Click to change</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the browser console (F12) for errors.  Are you opening your html page with a `file://` url?

Answer (score 0):

you might be getting CORS error as suggested, check the devtools console, are you trying to open the file directly in the browser by double clicking. use any http server like http-server , install it globally using the following command in the terminal or cmd

```
 npm i -g http-server
```

from terminal or cmd go to the folder where your html file and data.txt are present, and run the command

```
 http-server
```

visit the url and click the button and it should work